# All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed - EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am getting the above error when trying to add migration after add a foreign key using Entity Framework core.
I am adding FK in

```
public class ApplicantDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GrantProgramFK")]
        public GrantProgram GrantProgramId { get; set; }
 --------
   }
```

This FK ties to class

```
public class GrantProgram
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
   -----
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. I tried to remove the entity and run migration again, but failed.

Full error:

> The property 'GrantProgramId' cannot be removed from entity type 'EFDataAccessLibrary.Models.ApplicantDetail' because it is being used in the foreign key {'GrantProgramId'} on 'EFDataAccessLibrary.Models.ApplicantDetail'. All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed

I found a page,
[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.corestrings.propertyinuseforeignkey?view=efcore-3.1), but what does that mean? how to resolve it.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly was modified. Only the attribute? Or did you add `GrantProgramId` or changed its type?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by removing the "id" in the foreign key:

```
public class ApplicantDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GrantProgramFK")]
        public GrantProgram GrantProgram { get; set; }
 --------
   }
```

I still don't know why. If anybody can explain, or give a solution to leave "id" in it, don't hesitate to tell us.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. don't know the reason, but the error still pops up.

Comment: This solved for me too, curious if I can keep the ending Id in some way?

Comment: Without knowing the complete solution, I'd guess this has something to do with the [default naming of the primary key being either "ID" or "<TableName>Id"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key).

Answer (score 1):

Since entityframework auomatically uses any identifoer ending with 'ID or Id or id', ensure no other property name ends with 'ID or Id or id'

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, in my case all I did was undo the changes in AppDbContextModelSnapshot file (you can also delete the file) which is created in the migrations folder.

Turns out I had made an error before performing the migration, after which a model snapshot of my AppDbContext was created. After fixing the error, I tried the migration again, but the AppDbContextModelSnapshot was already modified, EF was not allowing to override with the same key of the same model **(*in this case GrantProgramFK from GrantProgram model*)**  . So just undo the changes in your AppDbContextModelSnapshot file and perform the migration again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to delete previous migrations file in the solution, this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by going into ModelSnapShot.cs in the Migrations folder and making sure to delete all references to the property causing issues. You'll be looking for any references to 'GrantProgramIdId'.

Make sure to delete any lines where the snapshot creates foreign keys.

Change any instance where the property name includes the incorrect property name above.

Make sure you check the entire file. There should be two separate places where issues exist.

Also, delete any migrations where this property was included, then create a new migration and should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. You have to delete(remove migration did not work either so I deleted manually) the migration and snapshot and change this field:

```
public GrantProgram GrantProgramId { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int GrantProgramId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same error. Below is what I've tried in order to resolve this error:

1. Renamed the ForeignKey attribute that has "Id" or "id" in it.
2. Deleted all migrations that were made before assigning the Foreign key property with "Id".

Answer (score -1):

You have to fix your classes before migration:

```
public class ApplicantDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
         public int? GrantProgramId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GrantProgramId")]
        [InverseProperty("ApplicantDetails")]
        public GrantProgram GrantProgram{ get; set; }
 --------
   }

public class GrantProgram
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       [InverseProperty(nameof(ApplicantDetail.GrantProram))]
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantDetail> ApplicantDetails{ get; set; }
   -----
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the error still shows.

Comment: The error says, 'All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed'. But I'm not trying to remove anything. what does EF mean by this.

Comment: @BGT did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

Add data annotations and everything will work smooth, see

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name ="Address Id")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? StateId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ZipCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class State
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name ="State Id")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```