# All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run migrations to create two models `Cart` and `CartItem`:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}

public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public string CartItemId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Cart")]
    public string CartRefId { get; set; }
    public Cart CartId { get; set; }
}
```

On running the `Add-Migration` command, I get the following error:

> The property 'CartId' cannot be removed from entity type 'ShopIt.Models.CartItem (Dictionary<string, object>)' because it is being used in the foreign key {'CartId'} on 'ShopIt.Models.CartItem (Dictionary<string, object>)'. All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed - EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168757/all-containing-foreign-keys-must-be-removed-or-redefined-before-the-property-can)

Comment: Remove the `ForeignKey` attribute (it's incorrect), name the `string` FK property `CartId` and navigation property `Cart`, and everything will be fine. i.e. `public string CartId { get; set; } public Cart Cart { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing the old migration.
use this command to remove migration. It removes the previous migration.

`Remove-Migration`